# Cannot enable or remove Gnome-Shell extension

Tags: 12.04, gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I have installed the [Classic Systray](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/04/gnome-shell-classic-systray-message.html) from the [Webupd8 Gnome3 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/gnome3). I use Gnome-Shell 3.4 with Precise, and this package is available for those. The problem is that I cannot enable it in the Gnome Tweak Tool. When I enable it nothing changes, and when I close Gnome Tweak and restart it it is disabled again. If I go to [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/local/) and try to enable it from there the same happens. The weird thing is that Classic Systray is still in the list when I remove the package. Isn't it normal that the extension will disappear in the list when it's deleted? And I have tried to reinstall it many times, but nothing seems to work. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried removing it manually?
Find the folder in /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ and delete it. Then, try to reinstall from [extension.gnome.org](http://extension.gnome.org)